# How to assign BrowserPath dynamically in Server2go app?

Tags: windows, server2go

This is my first post on stack overflow. I am using Server2go and Portable Firefox on a Pen Drive. There is a config file in Server2go named pms_config.ini. There is a line which allows you to specify the path to the Browser that am gonna use. Is there anyway to fetch the drive letter of the USB such that i can include it dynamically in the config file ?

```
[Browser]
;--- The browser that is started after server start (possible values: IEXPLORER,    FIREFOX, PORTABLEFIREFOX, MOZILLA, DEFAULT, EXTERNAL)
;--- Please take a look at the www.server2go-web.de/wiki pages for a documentation how to use PORTABLEFIREFOX!!!!!!!!
BrowserType=PORTABLEFIREFOX
;--- Browser command options like -k (NOT IN USE AT THE MOMENT)
BrowserCommandOptions=
;--- Path to an external browser that is used instead the browser above
BrowserPath=G:\FirefoxPortable\FirefoxPortable.exe 
;--- Specify caption text of Work Offline dialog box. You can use mor than one captions     (seperated with ;)
;--- The captions for german, english, french, dutch and spanish are build in by   default
WorkOfflineTitle=
;--- The size of the started browser. Can be a pixel dimension (1024x768) or the values MAXIMIZE and KIOSK (Internet Explorer only)
BrowserSize=
```

Is there anyway i could make the drive letter to be identified by an environment variable ?

Thank you for your help in advance :).

Answer (score 1):

From the Server2Go documentation on using Portable Firefox:
https://bitbucket.org/thaberkern/server2go/wiki/Using%20FirefoxPortable%20as%20browser%20from%20CD

You can leave out the drive letter:

```
BrowserPath=FirefoxPortable/FirefoxPortable.EXE
```